# What does sql error "Analytic function cannot be an argument of another analytic function" mean?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I wrote the following SQL query to find out orders whose maximum quantity is strictly greater than the average quantity of every order (including itself). One order consists of multiple products bought, and hence a quantity corresponding to each product. Refer the table in attached image

[Table:order_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx8CU.png)

SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.order_id
FROM
    (SELECT
         order_id,
         MAX(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) AS max_qty,
         AVG(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) AS avg_qty,
         MAX(AVG(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id)) OVER() AS max_avg_qty
     FROM
         ordersdetails) AS t
WHERE
    max_qty > max_avg_qty
ORDER BY
    order_id
```

It throws an error:

> Analytic function cannot be an argument of another analytic function

What does this mean?

I tried to get the answer using window functions. Using the window function:

```
avg(quantity) over(partition by order_id) as avg_qty,
```

I calculated average quantity bought for every order, then I put this
inside another window function `max() over()` in order to get maximum value among all the average quantities. But it didn't work.

Comment: Using an extra subquery can solve the issue.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using Big Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of operations that are stepping on each other's feet, from an order-of-operations standpoint.

There are three ways in Bigquery sql to filter a result set:

1. `WHERE` clause: This step is executed very early in query execution, often as a first step when selecting data from disk. This can't filter data that results from an aggregation either through a `GROUP BY` or a Window Function.
2. `HAVING` clause: This step is executed after `GROUP BY` aggregation and can be used to filter the result set based on that results of the `GROUP BY` aggregation.
3. `QUALIFY` clause: This step is executed at the very end of execution after Window Functions have been run against the result set.

Because you want to filter based on the results of window functions, a `QUALIFY` is the route you want to aim for.

To further complicate things, you are wanting to run a window function against data that is determined by another window function. This simply can't happen without a subquery as the step is only ran once per select.

Accounting for order of operations and limitations in step/processing that you have to deal with, your sql will look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.order_id
FROM
    (SELECT
         order_id,
         MAX(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) AS max_qty,
         AVG(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id) AS avg_qty         
     FROM
         ordersdetails) AS t
QUALIFY max_qty > MAX(avg_qty) OVER ()
ORDER BY order_id
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me. I learnt about a new keyword i.e. QUALIFY. I did not know about QUALIFY before this.

Comment: `QUALIFY` is newer and is starting to gain traction across RDBMS's. I think Teradata implemented it first. Bigquery, Snowflake, and Databricks all support it now. Without it, you can still write this logic, it would just need another subquery layer so you could apply the logic via a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just do:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM ordersdetails
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING MAX(quantity) > (
        SELECT avg(quantity)
        FROM ordersdetails
        )
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, it didn't work. Because the subquery 

```SELECT avg(quantity)
        FROM ordersdetails```

will give ```avg(quantity)``` of the entire table. I need to compare the ```max(quantity)``` with  ```avg(quantity)``` of every order_id.

Comment: "will give avg(quantity) of the entire table. "  "avg(quantity) of every order_id"  Those two things mean the same thing

Comment: I think you need a mathematics class. Suppose there are two students John and Smith. John got 60 marks in Maths and 80 marks in English. Average marks of john are (60+80)/2 = 70. Smith got 60 marks in math and 40 marks in English. Average of Smith is (60+40)/2 = 50. Average marks of both John and Smith are (60+80+60+40)/4 = 60. Now you tell me, Is the overall average i.e. 60 same as the individual averages of John and Smith? Then how can the average quantity of entire table be same as average quantity of every order id?